# Parallel tempering mcmc and space transformation

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

In parallel tempering mcmc you want to sample a probability density $p$ and to do this you sample $p$ and $p_i = p^{1/T_i}$ for a sequence of temperatures $T_i$. When $T_i$ is big the distribution is more flat and then you can swap states of the $p$ and $p_i$ samplers in order to ensure that the sampler for $p$ explores the space a little better.

One problem of this algorithm is that all the simulations for $p_i$ are unusable because it doesnt exist a transformation such that this simulations become samples of the original distribution.

In this case the transformation of the distribution has the form $f(p(x))$ with $f(z) = z^{1/T}$ but if the transformation were of the form $p(g(x))$
i.e. a space tranformation, we can use the change of variable theorem to use the samples of the tranformed variables. 
I imagine if $g$ is some kind of contraction then the transformed distribution is more flat than the original but I don't know if this would work.

Any ideas or references?

Thanks!

Comment: @User90803-> It is not clear what you mean by the phrase "i.e. a space transformation", by this do you mean to imply that you are placing a restriction on the structure of $g(x)$? I am unsure of what defines a space transformation (beside the usual change of variables) and how that would be helpful in your problem.